# Mensaje de Alerta en Tabla Dinámica PHP

Tags: php, mysql

me gustaría saber ¿Cómo puedo mandar un mensaje de Alerta cuando no encuentra resultados en la DB?

Consulto a un cliente mediante un input con una consulta desde php, y pinto la tabla en la vista con un AJAX.

Estoy tratando con un if, pero no me devuelve el mensaje de Error ....
Cualquier información sería de mucha ayuda, si necesitan ver más código estoy al pendiente, de antemano ¡Muchas Gracias!

```
if($stmt){

echo'<table class="table">
<tr> 
    <th>LINEACREDITO</th>
    <th>CREDITO ID</th>
    <th><center>PRODUCTO</center></th>
    <th>MONTO</th>
    <th>TASA FIJA</th>
    <th>APERTURA</th>
    <th>FECHA INICIO</th>
    <th>FECHA VENCIMIENTO</th>
    <th>ESTATUS</th>
    <th>SELECCIONAR</th>
</tr>';

    foreach($stmt as $row)
{

    echo'
<tbody id="listaRegistros">
    <tr>
        <td><center>'.$row["LineaCreditoID"].'</center></td>
        <td>'.$row["CreditoID"].'</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row["Producto"].'</td>
        <td>$ '.$row["MontoCredito"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["TasaFija"].' %</td>
        <td>$ '.$row["ComAperCont"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["FechaInicio"].'</td>
        <td><center>'.$row["FechaVencimien"].'</center></td>
        <td><center>'.$row["Estatus"].'</center></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="cbContratos" data-idRegistro="'.$row["CreditoID"].'" </td>
    </tr></tbody>';
   echo '<input type="hidden" id="clienteid" name="clienteid" value="'.$row["ClienteID"].'"/>';

}


echo '</table>';
echo'
<tr>
    <td><center><b>Nombre: </b> '.$row["NombreCompleto"].'</center></td>
    <td><center><b>Clave: </b> '.$row["ClienteID"].'</center></td>
</tr>';
}else{
    echo' <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="card alert alert-danger">
                                        <p>
                                            No se encontraron bonos para el cliente <?php echo $cteid; ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>';
}
}
```

Esto es lo que muestra cuando encuentra a un cliente en la DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui cuando no encuentra nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usando javascript con el `alert('mensaje')` o simplemente imprimiendo en el `if` un modal con el mensaje.

Comment: En donde declaras la variable `$stmt`?

Comment: La variable la declaro en la consulta $stmt = $connect->prepare ("CONSULTA");

Comment: @Kleith lo estoy tratando de hacer con el if, pero en el else no me regresa el mensaje de error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me imagino que estás usando PDO, entonces en la query podés preguntar por la cantidad de resultados devueltos con [`rowCount()`](https://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php), entonces en el condicional lo cambias por eso, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
  // Muestro la tabla tal como la venías mostrando...
} else {
  // Agrego el contenido para el alerta...
}
```

Comment: Listo utilice el código que me proporcionas y funciona muy bien, ahora tengo otra duda, en el input donde ingreso el cliente que quiero buscar, busco tanto por ClienteID (4 digitos) y por CreditoID (9 Digitos) con ese código que me mandaste hace bien solo con el cliente, pero con el credito me manda el mensaje de alerta ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? y por cierto si uso PDO

Comment: A ver si comprendo, tenés un `<input />` en donde ingresas: `ClienteID` o `CreditoID` y los dos utilizan la misma consulta? O bien tenés dos `<input />` y cada una corresponde a una consulta diferente?

Comment: Tengo un input para los dos

Comment: Probablemente tengas algo en la query que hace que esté devolviendo un valor para `CreditoID`.

Comment: Si claro, funcionaba bien antes de agregar la línea que me proporcionas

Comment: Olvídalo fue un error mio me sirve correctamente ¡Gracias por tu tiempo! Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Intenta chequear la cantidad de registros asi:

```
if(count($stmt)){
  //foreach para desplegar los registros
} else {
  //mensaje de alerta
}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, me sigue saliendo lo mismo...